# Express router.get fails, yet app.get works

Tags: node.js, express, middleware

While walking through [this tutorial](http://mherman.org/blog/2016/03/13/designing-a-restful-api-with-node-and-postgres/), I came across a problem wherein the router methods would not work. Using `npm start` and accessing localhost:3000/api/puppies gets a 404 error. However when I changed

```
var router = express.Router();
router.get('/api/puppies', db.getAllPuppies);
```

to

```
var app = express();
app.get('/api/puppies', db.getAllPuppies);
```

and run with `node index.js`, the data prints as expected. I've tried also putting at the beginning of my file

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/api/'));
```

but no joy. Is this something to do with `npm start`? At one point I literally copy/pasted the code out of the tutorial and still I get the 404s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A router has to be connected to your express app in order to be part of your server.

```
app.use(yourRouter);
```

Or, more commonly with a path that isolates that router's effect to just URLs that start with a specific path and the router's own URLs are relative to this path:

```
app.use('/somePath', yourRouter);
```

Without this, it's just a declared and configured router that isn't attached to any server.

Express documentation [examples here](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#router).

---

The tutorial you reference does not appear to show this part of using a router.

Comment: So `app.use('/api', router);
router.get('/api/puppies', db.getAllPuppies);` seems to make sense. However I still get the 404.

Comment: @1252748 - No.  You're registering url handlers for `/api/api/puppies`.  Remove one of the `/api` specifications.  FYI, the code in question from that tutorial is here: https://github.com/mjhea0/node-postgres-promises/blob/master/app.js#L24.  The tutorial uses `app.use('/', routes);`.

Comment: Hmm. He's complicated it a bit there. Your suggestion then is this: `app.use('/api', router);
router.get('/puppies', db.getAllPuppies);` It's the same error.

Comment: I believe it had to do with the start script from the express generator thing. when I do what you've instructed then just start the server with `app.listen` and run with `node index.js`, everything works fine. Thanks so much for your help!!

Comment: @1252748 - Yes, using `app.use('/api', router)` and then `router.get('/puppies');` is a good way to use a router as the `app.use()` scopes the whole router to a sub-path.